# Why was my answer referring to an interview with Elliott Carter unilaterally deleted?

Tags: discussion

Why was [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/71772/26407) deleted? How doesn't Elliott Carter answer the question in his video?

On 12 July 2018, I transcribed him. Please undelete?

I can't comment on deleted posts. So I reply here. Moderator "Dom" wrote:

> [Yes it compares new music and old music subjectively, but it fails to address old composers vs new composers (which do exist). It's also **based on someone else's opinion rather than any objective material.** The explanation "mean after all...the old days... you had all those feet soldiers marching and a horse...horses...trotting around and that's all in the music. Now it's airplanes and God-knows-what." is very showing of that.](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/why-isnt-there-a-classical-composer-like-beethoven-chopin-or-mozart-today/71772?noredirect=1#comment115199_71772)

I'm not sure how "it fails to address old composers vs new composers (which do exist)"? As "it compares new music and old music", it implies that some composers compose on the features of "new music"?

Wouldn't any answer to this question  must be "based on someone else's opinion rather than any objective material"?

> [[1.] Remember the following questions need to be answered: "Why isn't there a classical composer like Beethoven, Chopin or Mozart today? [2.] Why there aren't composers writing in a classical style today? [3.] Why don't we hear of classical composers today like we do of Beethoven, Chopin or Mozart?"](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/7222/dom)

[My other answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/71552/26407) answers these questions, as such:

1, 2. "it's still "I have an idea for making music that's more interesting to me than repeating other people's successful work." I then quoted how many different modernist composers innovate music.

3. "But not many people make music so central to their lives that they have time to explore these byways, especially in the mass-media glut of factory-produced tripe."

Answer (score 7):

It's a low quality answer (specifically a link only answer) and was flagged as such. Links rot away and if that happens, the answer you gave would literally have no content. The low quality queue even has link only answer selection due to these answers having the problem above. There's a similar post on that question that's also just a link to a YouTube video and it was deleted for the same reason.

Additional context from the [How to Answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) page:

> ### Provide context for links
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
> around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
> and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
> important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
> permanently offline.

I highly suggest you read all of the How to answer FAQ page and look at the other highly voted answers on the question. They should give you an idea of how to answer questions in general.

Comment: Please undelete now?

Comment: Flag the answer on the main site and it will be reviewed.

Comment: I can't comment on deleted posts. So I reply here.

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal please review the other answers on that question to get an idea of what your answer should look like. Also don't use your one deleted answer to justify the other. They are separate and both have different issues we keep trying to get you to see.